# Function timeout in Linkedin Marketing Developer Platform calls from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, linkedin-api, connection-timeout

We're developing a firebase cloud function to call Linkedin Marketing Developer Platform API and everything was fine until we got stuck in a specific call that does what it's supposed to do, but doesn't return anything and in 60 seconds we get "Function timeout" error.

The call is a ***POST*** to this URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2

We followed strictly the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-campaign-groups

---

Here is some information about what we do:

`URL`: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignGroupsV2

`Method`: POST

`Headers`:

- "Content-Type": "application/json"
- "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0"
- "x-li-format": "json"
- Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`

`Body`:

```
{
   account: `urn:li:sponsoredAccount:${ad_account}`,
   name: ad_name,
   runSchedule: {
      end: end_time_unix,
      start: start_time_unix,
   },
   status: status,
   totalBudget: {
      amount: "100.00", 
      currencyCode: "USD",
   },
}
```

It does create the Campaign Group but does not return anything to our fetch call and in 60 minutes fires the catch handle with "Function timeout" error.

Could you please tell us what we are doing wrong as all of the other calls we do (which are just to retrieve information) work as expected (using the same call method).

Thanks

p.s. We are doing JSON.stringify of the body before sending it to the API

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like it could be related to the Cloud Function's logic? You can maybe view the [trace details](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/viewing-details) to gain more insight as to why it takes a long time.

Comment: I will check that. Thank you. But how all the other calls that return some information without manipulating it (no create/edit/delete) return some data without a problem (using the same API call function), but the ones which require Linkedin to do some changes return nothing and the call endup with a timeout? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: I'm suspecting that maybe the payload is different? So the operations in the function don't yield the same result? In that case, the trace would tell you what's taking a long time in the operations.